# How would I access my constructor member in my class from an external function?

Tags: javascript

So, I am still a fresh man in JS. But I tried working around with my first bigger project. However, I just can't figure out why I can't access constructor members from functions that are outside of my main class. I assumed it had something to do with module.exports / require. So, that's how I did. Still, no luck.

Here is my code from the **main.js** file:

```
const funcs = require('./funcs.js');

class MainClass {
    constructor(omegga, config, store) {
        this.omegga = omegga;
        this.config = config;
        this.store = store;
    }
 async init() { 

    TestVehicle.on('cmd:test', async name => {
        const dss = await this.store.get('cats'); // this works fine.
        funcs.setSomething('29'); // this errors
        console.log(dss);
    });
  }
}
module.exports = MainClass;

async stop() { }
```

My function funcs.setSomething('29') errors however. Here's the function from **funcs.js**:

```
var MainClass = require('./main.js');
const teampo = new MainClass();

async function setSomething(argument1) {
    try {
        teampo.store.set('cats', argument1); // this errors
    } catch(e) { console.error(e); }
}
module.exports = { setSomething };
```

Now, JS tells me that something seems to be undefined. This is the error message I get:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined"

I wonder why it is undefined? Shouldn't I be able to inherit store and all of its properties/methods? I've tried everything already, like changing require, the module.exports, etc. But it doesn't seem to work. Might the cause be more severe or is this some simple mistake I do and just have been overseeing the whole time?

Comment: _“`new MainClass()`”_ — You aren’t passing anything here, so all three fields, `omegga`, `config`, and `store` are undefined. That’s why `teampo.store.set` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating the instance of the class here: `const teampo = new MainClass();`, you're not passing it the 3 things it requires which is

`constructor(omegga, config, store) {}`.

Since you didn't pass it a `store`, `this.store`, and thereby `teampo.store` is `undefined`

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay, that makes sense to me. So, would it be possible to write something like: const teampo = new MainClass(MainClass.store) ? And I am not sure exactly how I would pass it a store with the properties such like .get, .set, etc. 

Because if I pass it something, it just tells me that I'm accessing a non-existant property and I still get the same error, since it doesn't have .set() . Isn't it possible to copy it directly from my MainClass or is this not possible? (EDIT: Since "store" also contains values, I don't want it to create a completely new thing)

Comment: So you didn't write this class? For testing you can do something like `new MainClass(null, null, {get: () => {}, set: () => {}}` and maybe `console.log()` in those `get/set` methods

Comment: @T J What I'm running is a a server wrapper for a game. Basically, it wraps the console of the server of the game, to provide interactivity and utility via plugins. And I am just writing a plugin for it, but don't want to have all my functions I need bloated into the main.js, so I decided to put it into the funcs.js and require it into the main.js. But that's where my problem occurs, since I can't access any of the store.set, store.get, etc. methods from my funcs.js.

Comment: @T J Ahh, nvm. I just figured it out and it was easier than I thought. I basically just put my funcs.js into a new class, gave it a constructor and just this.store in my main.js over to the constructor member of my funcs.js. That did do it!

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate your class with `const teampo = new MainClass();` you’re not passing any arguments. The constructor sets store to one of the arguments (`this.store = store`). Since there’s no store argument, this.store is undefined.

So if you subsequently attempt to call `set` on it it errors.